# Spotting / checking an end of a sequence in C++

Tags: c++, input, stream, sequence, eof

I need to read an unknown length sequence of integers and then i need to find the longest monotonic subsequence in it. The sequence ends with EOF sign and its elements are to separated with spaces.
I'm not really bothering the algorytm of finding the subsequence now I'd like to make sure that I'm reading elements of the sequence in a right way. Below is a code which is supposed to do the job but there's a bug which I don't get right now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    int a=0;
    cout << "Give me a number: ";

     // while (!fin.eof()) {
           while (cin >> a) {

    cin >> a;
    sum +=a;
    cout << "Sum is: " <<sum << endl;



         /* Thats the place where whole magic is supposed to happen.
         I'm really confused however, because after entering i.e. 2 3 4 2 4 
         and pressing <Enter> five times shows an answer "The sum is  <proper sum>"
         and the answer "The final sum is: ... " doesn't show at all.
         */

    }
    cout << "final sum is : " << sum;

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'll be very grateful if anyone could answer my questions and explain if and where I'm wrong.
I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you seem to be checking on the state of `fin`, but you never open that file and you never read from it.  I'm guessing you meant to use `std::cin` everywhere, or `fin` everywhere; I'll stick to `std::cin`, but `fin` would work the same way.

The problem is that you first check for end-of-file and then read and use the data.  This means that if the read failed, you aren't told about this.  Instead of

```
while (std::cin) {
    std::cin >> a;
    sum += a;
}
```

use

```
while (std::cin >> a) {
    sum += a;
}
```

This will still perform the check, but *after* the read, meaning that if the read failed, you don't go into the body of the loop, and don't use the (nonsense) data.

The `fin` case looks much the same:

```
std::ifstream fin("mydata.txt");
while (fin >> a) {
    sum += a;
}
```

Note that there's no need to explicitly check for whether you reached the end of the file; checking the state of the stream will catch that error, as well as any errors due to being unable to parse a number.  If instead we did

```
while (fin >> a, !fin.eof())
```

this would correctly handle the case where you read the whole file, but loop infinitely if it contained something other than a number.

Comment: @lizusek: Because it only checks whether the end of the file has been reached.  It hasn't; but the stream failed to read, so it won't be able to read any further, either.

Comment: result of fin >> a isn't false in this case?

Comment: @lizusek: The comma operator evaluates but ignores the result of the left-hand side; it doesn't matter whether it's true or false.

Comment: Thank u, yeap that worked too without using EOF. But I still don't get it why this code doesn't produce the line "final sum is: ..." ?

Comment: @AntonGolov so only right-most expression is a condition? Other are just evaluated?

Comment: @vladimir1923: Could you please put it on ideone.com and show the result there?

Comment: @AntonGolov http://ideone.com/weBB8e but the output now is null because all the number in input I give from my keyboard... Maybe can I change my original post and add some output there? Can I?

Comment: @vladimir1923: You can provide input on ideone: http://ideone.com/zOEoj1  Your code works as expected.  I think fixing the issues Mike and I brought up was all there was to it.

Comment: @AntonGolov http://ideone.com/0BpQZp there's a version with sample input. The option that I've just found. And on this online compiler the code works well, but on my I have problems. I'm using CodeBlocks do you think that it might be the reason?

Comment: @vladimir1923: No, I think the problem is solved.  You should probably start a new question if you run into further issues.

Comment: @AntonGolov thank U one more time, I've put the code on the online compiler and everything works but on CodeBlocks and on VisualStudio id doesn't show the last line. Thank u very anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First, decide whether you're reading from the file (`fin`) or the program's input (`std::cin`). Currently, you're reading from one and checking the other for `eof`.

If you're reading from the file, then you'll need to open it. Otherwise, remove `fin` to avoid confusion.

Then you should check for `eof` (and other error conditions) *after* attempting to read, and *before* using the result:

```
while (std::cin >> a) {  // or `fin`, if that's where you're reading from
    // your code using 'a' here
}
```

Comment: Yes that was my bad, but I didn't know that EOF works with integers object as well. But still I don't know why the code doesn't give me the answer "the final sum is: ... " of course there are no pointer that would change the value, but anyway sum was initialized with "O" should at least that value should be show, don't u think?